# Formatting text in NSTextView

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have a case where i'm getting formatted text with `<a href ...>`, `<em>`, `<br>`, `&quot;`, etc tags, and i'm showing it in a Text View. How can i apply these formats? If i can't, whats the most generic way to remove all these tags?

Thanks,
Mustafa

---

No, i just want to show the formatted text in non editable NSTextView. or maybe UIWebView, will it automatically handle tags like `<em>`?

Comment: NSTextView is a Mac OS X Cocoa class. UITextView is the iPhone equivalent.

Comment: UIWebView will handle all tags like a browser does. So you can use UIWebView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want editable text you will have to parse it using a library like [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to get just an NSString and then pass that to UITextView's `-setText:` method

If you need to display HTML, use UIWebView.

If you want to edit HTML as formatted text you will have to roll your own or use private API's.